# Why Manual prefetch (via select/columns) not supported with accessor 'multi'?

Tags: relationship, dbix-class

When I run code:

```
  return  $self->result_source->schema->resultset('Locality')->search(
      {
        'addresses_view.usage' => 0
        ,'me.id' => $self->id
      }
      ,{
        join => { servers => 'addresses_view' }
      }
    );
```

The next sql query generated:

```
SELECT 
  "me"."id", "me"."active", "me"."priority", 
  "me"."country_id", "me"."name"
FROM "localities" "me"
LEFT JOIN "servers" "servers" ON "servers"."locality_id" = "me"."id" 
LEFT JOIN "pool_addresses_view" "addresses_view" ON "addresses_view"."server_id" = "servers"."id" 
WHERE ( ( "addresses_view"."usage" = ? AND "me"."id" = ? ) )
```

And executed OK.

But when I want to add columns to 'SELECT'

```
    ,'+columns' => [ 'addresses_view.ip', 'addresses_view.id' ]
```

I get error: `Manual prefetch (via select/columns) not supported with accessor 'multi'`

I have found same qestion at [www.mail-archive.com/dbix-class@](https://www.mail-archive.com/dbix-class@lists.scsys.co.uk/msg05135.html), but I do not understand how *pass the columns attribute to search_related as well to restrict the columns to select*

Is there a way to add columns to 'SELECT' clause?

Answer (score 0):

[DBIx::Class::ResultSet#prefetch](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet#prefetch) is just sugar which internally populates the join and columns attributes.

[DBIx::Class::Manual::Joining](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Joining.pod#FETCHING-RELATED-DATA) contains lots of useful info about what's possible and how which should answer your question.